# Xamarin iOS: Simulator Works but Phone is blank

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I got a Xamarin iOS Project with a PCL. The App works fine when I deploy it to a Simulator. But on a real device it just shows a blank screen. No errors in Logs. 
 Anyone got a similar problem or can me direct where to search for the cause?

Comment: Maybe provide a little bit more about your project, structure, or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the same simulator as the device type (e.g. iPhone versus iPad) as it's common to have have different `.nib` files for both device types.

IOW if you only added UI elements to the iPhone UI and you're running this on an iPad device then you'll get a blank screen.

Look for code that looks like:

```
public partial class Hello_UniversalViewController : UIViewController
{
    static bool UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone {
        get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone; }
    }

    public Hello_UniversalViewController ()
        : base (UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone ? "Hello_UniversalViewController_iPhone" : "Hello_UniversalViewController_iPad", null)
    {
    }
}
```